# Illegal parameter number in definition of \NewCount

Tags: enumerate, itemize

So I am writing a huge document (its pretty long and I am not attaching the whole thing, but if it is needed then I can add it too).
By only including, itemize or enumerate, like

```
% Above text has Lots of text above with citations, drawing, plots, graphs, svg files etc

\begin{itemize} 
\item Hi all 
\end{itemize}

% Below text also has Lots of text above with citations, drawing, plots, graphs, svg files etc
```

then, I get the following errors:

```
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.430     \item
                Hi All
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
```

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@bbl@data 
                         
l.430     \item
                Hi All
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

)
```

```
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 430.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> LCR.tex
           
The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

! Emergency stop.
<*> LCR.tex
           
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 48270 strings out of 475237
 1125062 string characters out of 5764570
 2053591 words of memory out of 5000000
 68616 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 570557 words of font info for 85 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 128i,16n,124p,1680b,2229s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

```
In one of the folders in overleaf, I have a file which kind of serves as a preamble 

% MASTER OF SCIENCE THESIS TEMPLATE 2018
% TEMPLATE AUTHOR: TOMAS CASSANELLI

% INITIAL CONFIGURATION
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage[              % Left and right margins
    DIV=11,               % You can play with these numbers for a better
    BCOR=2mm,             % reference look into KOMA-Script CTAN manual
    headinclude=true,
    footinclude=false,
    paper=A4
    ]{typearea}

% BASIC THESIS INFORMATION
\def\title{Thesis not too long title}
\def\thesisauthor{Your name goes here}

% commands below work only for twoside option of \documentclass
\makeatletter
\if@twoside
    \newlength{\textblockoffset}
    \setlength{\textblockoffset}{10mm}
    \addtolength{\hoffset}{\textblockoffset}
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-2.0\textblockoffset}
\fi
\makeatother

% PACKAGES
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}  % Basic math packages
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{references/bibfile_thesis.bib} %Import the bibliography file                  % A&A bibliograsphy style
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[svgpath=./figures/]{svg}
\usepackage{upgreek}                   % More greek letters
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}


% to know the page width and adjust the image size!
\usepackage{printlen} % \uselengthunit{in}\printlength{\textwidth}
\usepackage[allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
% TABLE PACKAGES
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\small}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor={blue}}  

% IMAGES PACAKGES
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\graphicspath{{../figures/}}

% TIKZ & PGFPLOTS
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,
    patterns,
    circuits.logic.US,
    circuits.ee.IEC,
    intersections,
    angles,
    quotes,
    arrows,
    shapes,
    }

% COLOR BOX
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{note}{
    fontupper=\small,
    title=Note,
    arc=0mm,
    sharp corners,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\small
    }
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}% for simpler customization of used lists
\setlist[itemize]{label= --}
\MakeRobust\@centercr
% DEDICATION PAGE CONFIGURATION
\newenvironment{dedication}
  {\clearpage
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
   \itshape
   \raggedleft}
  {\par
   \vspace{\stretch{3}}
   \clearpage}

% PDF CONFIGURATION
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdffitwindow=true,
    pdfstartview={FitH},
    pdftitle={MSc Thesis},                    % TITLE
    pdfauthor={Your name goes here},          % AUTHOR
    pdfsubject={\title},                      % DOCUMENT SUBJECT
    pdfcreator={Tomas Cassanelli},            % CREATOR
    pdfproducer={\thesisauthor},              % PRODUCER
    pdfkeywords={Astronomy, Astrophysics},
    pdfnewwindow=true,
    colorlinks=true,                          % COMMENT FOR BLACK LINKS
    linkcolor=red,
    citecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=RoyalBlue
    }

% DRAFT MODE: uncomment this for draft mode!
% \usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
% \newwatermark[allpages,color=red!10,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT}

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter  % front and main matter to make roman numbers in between.

    % FIRST PAGE TITLE
    \pdfbookmark[0]{Title page}{title}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace{0.5cm}

            \Huge
            \textbf{\title}

            \vspace{0.5cm}
            \LARGE
            % Thesis Subtitleb

            \vspace{1.5cm}

            \textbf{\thesisauthor}

            \vspace{4cm}

            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics{logo_aifa}
            \end{center}

            \vfill

            Masterarbeit in Astrophysik\\
            angefertigt im Argelander Institut f\"ur Astronomie

            \vspace{0.5cm}

            \Large
            vorgelegt der \\
            Mathematisch-Naturwissenschalftlichen Fakult\"at \\
            der \\
            Rheinische Friedrich-Wilhelms-Universit\"at Bonn\\
            Deutschland

            \vspace{0.5cm}

            \LARGE
            \today

        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}

    \newpage  % Inserting empty page
    \mbox{}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    % DEDICATION
    \begin{dedication}
    \pdfbookmark[0]{Dedication}{dedication}
    To Google and Wikipedia
    \end{dedication}

    \newpage  % Inserting empty page
    \mbox{}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    % SIGNATURE PAGE
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \pdfbookmark[0]{Statement}{statement}
    \par\vspace*{\fill}
    \noindent I hereby declare that this thesis was formulated by myself and that no sources or tools than those cited were used.
    \vspace{0.8cm}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{c@{\hskip 1in}c}
            \makebox[2in]{\hrulefill} & \makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}\\
            Date & Signature\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{1cm}

    \noindent 1. Gutachter: Prof. Dr. (Professor Name 1) \\
    \noindent 2. Gutachter: Prof. Dr. (Professor Name 2)

    \newpage  % Inserting empty page
    \mbox{}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    % ABSTRACT
    \subfile{../abstract/abstract}

    % ACKNOWLEDGMENTS
    \subfile{../acknowledgments/acknowledgments}

    % TABLE OF CONTENT
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
    \tableofcontents

    % LIST OF FIGURES
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \listoffigures

    % LIST OF TABLES
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
    \listoftables

    \newpage  % Inserting empty page
    \mbox{}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \mainmatter  % front and main matter to make roman numbers in between

    % BODY
    \subfile{../chapter1/chapter1.tex}
    \subfile{../chapter2/LCR.tex}
    %\subfile{../chapter3/chapter3}
    %\subfile{../chapter4/chapter4}
    %\subfile{../chapter5/chapter5}

    % APPENDICES
    \appendix
    \subfile{../appendix1/appendix1}
    %\subfile{../appendix2/appendix2}
    %\subfile{../appendix3/appendix3}

    % REFERENCES
    % If you are using a windows machine and the bibliography doesn't work
    % remove the extension for .bst and .bib files here!
    \bibliographystyle{../references/bibstyle_aa.bst}
    \bibliography{../references/bibfile_thesis.bib}
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Do you know where the error could be?
If you do need the whole file, then I can share it
too and will detail how you might have to open it.
EDITED:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EX9KAVjS6ms3PL0odVWy947Hsr0Uu5xd/view?usp=drive_link

This is the link to the google drive which has my file. I decided to add my whole file since I am unable to post a small part of my code which would represent the whole problem. Here open chapter 2 and click on LCR.tex and run it and then you will see the error.

Comment: the error is in some biblatex code but you should make a small but complete example that shows the error.

Comment: your example does not help as no one can run it, please post an example that shows the problem, however you seem to be loading many conflicting packages notably enumerate and enumitem do not load both

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EX9KAVjS6ms3PL0odVWy947Hsr0Uu5xd/view?usp=drive_link

Here is a link to the google drive which has my zip file. For some reason I am unable to upload it on stackexchange. Please open chapter 2, open LCR.tex file and then just run it. I use overleaf for this.

Comment: Copy everything over to a new project.  Delete everything that you think isn't related to the error, a chunk at a time.  You should be able to get it down to 30 lines (or even 10).

Comment: Please don't just give us all of your code, as it's unreasonable for us to comb over your entire thesis to find the error. Like @DavidCarlisle said, please make a [minimal viable example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/270231) that still demonstrates the problem—emphasis on "minimal" and "viable".

Comment: no do not use external links. delete everything apart from the part of the document that gives the error, then delete every part of the preamble loading packages not used in your example and so make a small one-page complete document that shows your error.

Comment: You have much more than one error. You seem to have ignored them all the time and now fall over. Start to correct the first error. Btw: `\bibliographystyle{../references/bibstyle_aa.bst}
    \bibliography{../references/bibfile_thesis.bib}` is wrong with biblatex.